# Python Replacing Strings with Dictionary values

Tags: python, regex, dictionary

Based on the given input:

> I can do waaaaaaaaaaaaay better :DDDD!!!! I am sooooooooo exicted about it :))) Good !!

Desired: output

> I can do way/LNG better :D/LNG !/LNG I am so/LNG exicted about it :)/LNG Good !/LNG

--- Challenges:

1. better vs. soooooooooo >> we need to keep the first one as is but shorten the second
2. for the second we need to add a tag (LNG) as it might have some importance for intensification for subjectivity and sentiment

---- Problem: error message "unbalanced parentheses"

Any ideas?

My code is:

```
import re 

lengWords = {} # a dictionary of lengthened words 

def removeDuplicates(corpus):

data = (open(corpus, 'r').read()).split()
myString = " ".join(data)

for word in data:
    for chr in word: 
        countChr = word.count(chr)
        if countChr >= 3: 
            lengWords[word] = word+"/LNG"
            lengWords[word] = re.sub(r'([A-Za-z])\1+', r'\1', lengWords[word])
            lengWords[word] = re.sub(r'([\'\!\~\.\?\,\.,\),\(])\1+', r'\1', lengWords[word])                             

    for k, v in lengWords.items():
        if k == word: 
            re.sub(word, v, myString)
return myString
```

Comment: Why all the backslashes and duplicated characters in the second character group? Neither makes your code particularly easy on the eye.

Comment: Are you looking to replace any sequence of repeated letters with just one letter? Wouldn't this replace "good" with "god" then?

Comment: :DDDD is shorter than :D/LNG. Same to !!!!, ))) and !!. I think it should limit the translation to cases where the result is actually shorten than the original, like waaaaaaaaaaaaay and sooooooooo.

Comment: @interjay in that case i think that he should first discard any word in the english (or language) dictionary.

Comment: [Don't do `for... if`.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/12/27/10251210.aspx)

Comment: Unbalanced parentheses on which line? This is a syntax error right? You don't need to surround the `open` command in parentheses of its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the perfect solution, but I don't have time to refine it now- just wanted to get you started with easy approach:

```
s = "I can do waaaaaaaaaaaaay better :DDDD!!!! I am sooooooooo exicted about it :))) Good !!"
re.sub(r'(.)(\1{2,})',r'\1/LNG',s)
>> 'I can do wa/LNGy better :D/LNG!/LNG I am so/LNG exicted about it :)/LNG Good !!'
```